# Why does Consolas in Visual Studio look bold?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2005, fonts

I have tried installing the Consolas font pack so that I can use it with VS 2005. For some reason it looks a lot bolder than [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas) and [Jeff Atwood's](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000356.html) examples. I read something about anti-aliasing and I am trying that now. Any ideas on how to get it too look thin and sleak?

EDIT:
Sorry found out. It has something to do with ClearType fonts. Turning it on sorted out all my problems.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and then accept it! That way people will be able to find the solution easily later on ;-)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977672/how-to-disable-cleartype-in-visual-studio-2010/12183738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on the clearType by running through the wizard from MS website below,

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

Comment: Actually this is __wrong__ and won't do it.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960430/possible-to-adjust-cleartype-on-visual-studio-2010/12183738#12183738) for how to turn off BlurType.

Answer (score 1):

It looks bolder when your Windows OS (XP?) has [Font smoothing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306527) turned on.

Right click your Desktop > Properties > Appearance tab > Effects > "Use the following method to smoothe screen fonts".

Try changing it to ClearType / Standard / Turn it off. Keep switching back to VS and scroll up/down a bit to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you have ClearType activated?