# Possible to adjust ClearType on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, cleartype

I just got VS 2010 beta 1, but the text in the text editor is thin, ie not anti aliased, smoothed or cleartyped. It's hard to read. Is there a setting to adjust it, similar to the one in the OS.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574738/why-does-consolas-in-visual-studio-look-bold/574752

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the beta. See [the readme](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/A/0/7A023209-096F-4F7D-B2BC-831ECC68FF5B/VS2010Beta1Readme.htm). Section 2.4.2.2 "Text may appear slighly blurry".

They are working on a fix and recommend you stick with Consolas font for English, for now.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in Beta 2 once WPF integrates with the DirectWrite code in the latest versions of DirectX.

Answer (score 2):

> To workaround this, we decided to override the OS Setting and always for ClearType smoothing to be on when Consolas is the editor font. This way the user who isn't particular about fonts gets the best behaviour and if the user wants to have a non-clear type experience the will also need to switch their font which they would have to do anyways.

[ClearType cannot be disabled in source code windows](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/504099/cleartype-cannot-be-disabled-in-source-code-windows?wa=wsignin1.0)

Let me know if changing the font from Consolas works for you.

Comment: I changed font from Consolas to Courier new and it's not cleartyped. Thank you.

Consolas always uses ClearType.

Comment: I am using Courier New and it is still ClearTyped.

Comment: __Actually ClearType can be disabled__, but you need an __extension__ to do it.  [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12183738/111307).

Comment: Bill The Lizard deleted my answer, but the right answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574738/why-does-consolas-in-visual-studio-look-bold/12183639#12183639)

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft H4X0RS decided to [***force*** users to adopt ClearType when using Consolas font](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/visual-studio-2010-text-clarity-cleartype-and-aliased-fonts.aspx) (scroll down until you see the heading **Consolas always uses ClearType**)

The way to fix this is to install the [Text Sharp extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7aafa2ea-8c54-4da8-922e-d26bf018514d/) (*yes, you read right, you need to install an **extension** to turn off BlurType -- ie to have your system-wide setting of no anti-aliasing applied*)

How the people who did this got away with it I'll never know.

Comment: Aliased is really nasty, and Grayscale seems like it's exactly the same as ClearType? Any suggestions for a combination with a different font?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension that can help with this:

http://www.svprogramming.net/text-sharp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to both turn it off in the display options and the performance options:
[Visual Studio 2010 Text Clarity: ClearType Options](https://web.archive.org/web/20151027232043/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/visual-studio-2010-text-clarity-cleartype-and-aliased-fonts.aspx)