# How to disable ClearType in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cleartype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to adjust ClearType on Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960430/possible-to-adjust-cleartype-on-visual-studio-2010)

How to do that? I can't find solution.
VS 2010 version: 10.0.30319.1