# Why are my fonts blurry in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts

I recently switched to Visual Studio 2010. 
I have always used good old pixelized fonts as I find it easier to read (One pixel is Black, the other is white... Perfect).

In Visual Studio 2005 I was using bitmap fonts. In VS 2010 It seems that you must use TTF Fonts, so I switched to [proggy fonts TTF format](http://www.proggyfonts.com/index.php?menu=download).

But now my text is blurry. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

How can I disable this useless feature?
I don't want my code to look "pretty" i just want to work with it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable ClearType in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977672/how-to-disable-cleartype-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try with this tool that was a great solution only for remove clear type on code (text view).
http://vlasovstudio.com/text-sharp/index.html
I want to have in windows 8 a high dpi options like currently linux versions (for instance cinnamon, excelent and flexible controls to high dpi screens).
I am working with vstudio 2013 and lenovo yoga 2 pro.

Answer (score 1):

It is Windows 7 operating system property.

- Right click on "Computer" and select "Properties".
- Click "Advanced system settings" at the left top corner. "System Properties" dialog box appears.
- Click "Settings..." button under "Performance" section.
- Uncheck "Smooth edges of screen fonts".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Clear Type that's causing the problem, try disabling that in the OS.

Comment: Disabling Clear Type solve the issue on non-microsoft fonts. But it enhance the blurry effect of microsoft fonts (fonts tweaked for clear type?) Can i just disable Clear Type in Visual Studio?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of default system font vs proggy ttf font without cleartype (zoom mismatch) http://img64.imageshack.us/i/blurry2.png/