# How to fix blurry menus in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional on a Windows 10 machine with an Intel integrated GPU and high resolution Display Port monitors. DPI in Windows is set to 100% and I haven't done much with the computer besides using Visual Studio.

Suddenly when I came back to my computer (some of) the texts in Visual Studio were blurry, including items in the Solution Explorer as well as menus. Just everything blurry.

[image]

If I hover something the hovered something will become sharp again but moving the window doesn't make the text sharp but makes the blur change.

How to make the texts in Visual Studio sharp again?

Comment: You can check this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153414/why-are-my-fonts-blurry-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: The issue appears in other places in the OS as well now.

Comment: Sure, this is an OS problem, not a VS problem.  Time to reboot the machine.  And look for a video driver update.

Comment: disable HW acceleration in VS options and also update the GPU driver.

Comment: Reboots didn't help and no video driver update available. Ended up refreshing the computer and now it's fine.